# RGTK2, GTK, GLIB package install on EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, gtk, glib, microstrategy

On an EC2 machine, I am trying to install R Integration pack for connecting R with Microstrategy. In the installation of the package MicroStrategyR on R, I got following errors.

```
ERROR: gtk+2.0 not found by pkg-config.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘cairoDevice’
```

I tried to install RGtk2 separately which failed with following error.

```
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
```

So I downloaded following source `gtk+-3.19.3.tar.xz` and tried to run ./configure in the unzipped folder. And it fails with following errors.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.45.8    atk >= 2.15.1    pango >= 1.37.3    cairo >= 1.14.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'atk' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found
No package 'cairo-gobject' found
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

I tried adding following to the environment variable, and ran it but it resulted in same error.

```
% export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

So I now downloaded `glib-2.45.8.tar.xz` and tried to run ./configure in this. And it runs successfully. However when I go back and rerun configure in GTK folder I still get following error.

```
No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

Also I checked for cairo, but GTK installation process is not able to find the cairo package.

% sudo yum list cairo
Loaded plugins: priorities, security
Installed Packages
cairo.x86_64

Am I missing some configuration of any environment variable?

**Update:**
Following packages are installed, but atk installation is not found in packages.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install glib2.x86_64
sudo yum install pycairo-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install pango-devel.x86_64
```

I am still facing issues with gtk+-2.10.14 not being able to recognize atk installed from source and gtk+-2.8.0 also not recognizing atk installed from source.

ATK installation steps used:

```
tar xvf atk-1.9.0.tar.gz
cd atk-1.9.0
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

No errors during these ATK steps. Added /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Not sure why GTK configure is not able to recognize ATK. Am I missing some step after make install.

**Second update:**
I copied atk.pc into /usr/lib64/pkgconfig folder, but RGtk2 is still not able to find it.

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config --list-all|grep -i 'gtk'
gtk+-2.0              GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit (x11 target)
gtk-doc               gtk-doc - API documentation generator
gtk+-x11-2.0          GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit (x11 target)
gtk+-unix-print-2.0   GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit Unix print support
```

R Error:

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
```

**Third Update:**
Looks like we have to install gtk-devel package which is not available for EC2. Need to figure out building it from source, but individual versions of gtk-devel are looking for different gtk versions. Why should this be so hard?

Thanks.

Comment: First, you downloaded GTK+ 3, not GTK+ 2. Second, the `pkg-config` name is `gtk+-2.0`, not `gtk+2.0`. Third, and most important, you really need to do a search in the package manager to see if GTK+ and GLib are available there. I don't know how to do that with yum; sorry. I do know that you might need to install `-devel` packages separately for things like cairo and GLib. Fourth, `./configure` alone isn't enough to build a library; you must also `make` and then `sudo make install` it (but ONLY IF it's not in the package repositories). Fifth, you may need to `export` env vars from the shell.

Comment: I don't think you actually need to set `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` though; it should be set automatically by the distribution maintainer. And last, if EC2 doesn't have its own X server, you'll need to do something like `ssh -X` to be able to run the program from your server to host on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks andlabs. I used export for env variable. Edited the question. I also installed yum groupinstall "Development Tools". But for installing gtk, I still get the following error.

Comment: % sudo yum install gtk+-devel gtk2-devel     ||||||                    
Loaded plugins: priorities, security               ||||||                   
Setting up Install Process                             ||||||                     
No package gtk+-devel available.                ||||||           
No package gtk2-devel available.                ||||||                   
Error: Nothing to do                                     ||||||

Comment: Does your shell tab-complete packages in yum? If so try that; if not you'll need to use yum's searching options.

Comment: % sudo yum search gtk              ||||||||||
Loaded plugins: priorities, security           ||||||||||
============================================================================================================= N/S Matched: gtk    ||||||||||  ==============================================================================================================
gtk-doc.noarch : API documentation generation tool for GTK+ and GNOME    ||||||||||

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.||||||||||

Comment: Ok. I now installed glib by using sudo yum install glib2.x86_64. Now while running configure for gtk+-2.10.14 I am only getting atk, pango, cairo missing messages. Let me find them as well.

Comment: % sudo yum search all atk     |||||||||
Loaded plugins: priorities, security         |||||||||
Warning: No matches found for: atk        |||||||||
No Matches found                                   |||||||||

Comment: Then you will need to contact EC2 for more instructions. I don't use EC2 at this time so I don't know it; sorry.

Comment: sudo yum install pycairo-devel.x86_64 - is now installed and gtk is now only showing atk, pango missing message. down to two.

Comment: Almost there.. only atk pending.. sudo yum install pango-devel.x86_64 - done

Comment: I am stuck at the step of installing atk... I installed atk-1.9.0 by using configure->make -> make install. I dont see any errors there, but when I tried to install gtk+-2.10.14, using configure step throws the same error as   ||||||| checking for BASE_DEPENDENCIES... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.12.0    atk >= 1.9.0    pango >= 1.12.0    cairo >= 1.2.0) were not met:

||||||||||||No package 'atk' found

Comment: I also added additional pkgconfig locations - export $PKG_CONFIG_PATH=
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig

Comment: I copied atk.pc into /usr/lib64/pkgconfig from /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ and ran ldconfig and the gtk+-2.10.14 configure and install ran successfully. But RGtk2 is still not able to find the location of GTK install.

Comment: It shows that the gtk is installed from pkg-config, but it RGtk2 is still looking for GTK-2.8.0.         /usr/bin/pkg-config --list-all|grep -i 'gtk'            ||||||||||
gtk+-2.0              GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit (x11 target)            ||||||||||
gtk-doc               gtk-doc - API documentation generator            ||||||||||
gtk+-x11-2.0          GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit (x11 target)            ||||||||||
gtk+-unix-print-2.0   GTK+ - GIMP Tool Kit Unix print support            ||||||||||